# Check if string exists in Many-to-one relationships

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

I try to code a simple Shopping-Cart in Django and have the following models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    serial = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Cart(models.Model):
    user        = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    products    = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True)
    updated     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = CartManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)


class CartEntry(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

How would i check if a CartEntry already exists for the Product, so i can increment the quantity +1, when it already exists or create a CartEntry when it does not exists?

I think about something like this:

```
def cart_update(request, id):

    product_id = id

    my_cart_id, my_cart = Cart.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)

    product_obj = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)

    product_quantity = "1"

    for item in CartEntry.objects.filter(cart=my_cart_id):
        #check all products in CartEntry if it already exists
        if not item.product.exists():
            #Product does not exists yet - creating a CartEntry
            CartEntry.objects.create(cart=my_cart_id, product=product_obj, quantity=product_quantity)
        else:
            #Product does exists - incrementing the quantity

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('list-products'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i got it:

```
class CartEntry(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.product.name)
```

-

```
from django.db.models import F

def cart_update(request, id):
    product_id = id

    my_cart_id, my_cart_created = Cart.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)

    product_obj = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)

    product_quantity = "1"

    items_in_cart = CartEntry.objects.filter(cart=my_cart_id)

    # if no products in cart, add product
    if not items_in_cart:
        CartEntry.objects.create(cart=my_cart_id, product=product_obj, quantity=product_quantity)
    else:
        # if product already exists in Cart, increment quantity +1
        if CartEntry.objects.filter(cart=my_cart_id).filter(product=product_obj):
            CartEntry.objects.filter(cart=my_cart_id, product=product_obj).update(quantity=F('quantity')+1)
        else:
            # product does not exist in Cart -> add it with quantity 1
            CartEntry.objects.create(cart=my_cart_id, product=product_obj, quantity=product_quantity)


    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('list-products'))
```

edits or other (better) solutions are ofcourse welcome.